# Gmail does not receive mail from my server

Tags: server, email, postfix, gmail, smtp

Install Postfix on my server
You have set all settings
But the problem is that the server sends mail to all servers except Gmail

Have any of you experienced this problem before?
How can I solve it?

Comment: What's the error message? Probably have to set up a relayhost in /etc/postfix/main.cf

Comment: Thanks for your interest
You have added a subdomain from the domain linked to the same IP server as the name of the host.
But the problem has not yet been solved.

Comment: Do you mean Gmail doesn't receive it, or that server doesn't send it? If it's the former it could be filtering, which I've experienced with gmail - mail sent is basically blackholed.

Comment: Gmail does not receive mail, but in the mailing list on the server it appears that the email has been sent.

Comment: this is sent status in sent file :

Comment: From root Sun Mar 17 16:18:57 2019
Date: Sun, 17 Mar 2019 16:18:57 -0400
To: android.com111@gmail.com
Subject: important mail
User-Agent: s-nail v14.8.6

this is a body massegsgsgsgsgsg hvjasd jasbdiuas diasdih jasd asmdkasbdix adk